# Sequence convergence without metric equivalence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

I only have problem in the metric equivalence part. I think there exists an equivalence. $R^\infty$ is a subspace of $R^\omega$. Let's use the uniform topology for $R^\omega$ and use the relative topology for $R^\infty$. Let the metric for the uniform topology be $d$. Obviously the defined convergence implies convergence of relative $d$. The other direction is also obvious. The requirement of $y(m)_j=y(0)_j=0$ is automatically satisfied since the space is $R^\infty$.

I think the requirement of $y(m)_j=y(0)_j=0$ is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The other direction is also obvious.

I don't believe so. Show it then? In detail. How do you get **one** $k$ that works for all $m$, as you need? Convergence in $d$ doesn't give you that, even in $R^\infty$. Every sequence (point) in the sequence can have its own cut-off point, going further and further back, while still converging uniformly.

The convergence induces a topology (in the usual way) and as we have a linear space in that topology (I think $+$ and scalar multiplication are continuous) it will be induced by a metric iff it is first countable. So to show your problem, try to refute that.

Comment: Is the following counterexample correct? For example, $z_1=(1,0,0,0,...)$, $z_2=(1/2,1/2,0,0...)$, $z_3=(1/3,1/3,1/3,0,...)$, etc. Then every $z_n$ is in $R^\infty$. And it converges to $z=(0,0,0,0,...)$ in uniform topology. But it does not converge in the C sense since no common cut-off point exists. Can I use this counter for any metric besides the uniform topology?

Comment: @JunkWarrior that example works to show the uniform metric does not work, but it doesn’t show that **no** metric can work. That needs more work, I think. You must have learned theorems about it.

Comment: What theorems do you mean? I know similar problems like "$R^\omega$ in the box topology is not metrizable". These problems use the sequence lemma. Use a subset. Find a limit point in the closure of the subset. Then show no sequence converges to that point. The difficulty here is that the topology is not explicitly mentioned.